# check dynamic if a class responds to a selector by respondsToSelector:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am looking for a possibility to check in a dynamic way if a class responds to a selector.

For example I have a strict schema of method names in a class like "parse[CountryCode]Adress".

I tryed something like this:

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"parse%@Address", @"DE"]);

if ([CountryTraderDataParser respondsToSelector:@selector(selector)]) {
    NSLog(@"responds to");
    [CountryTraderDataParser selector];
}
```

but this doesn't work.

With a hard coded line `[CountryTraderDataParser respondsToSelector:@selector(parseDEAddress:)]` this example works fine.

Is there an other/better way to get this example to work?

Comment: I think you should remove `@selector`, since it already is a selector.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `selector` variable is already a selector (type `SEL`), so you shouldn’t use `@selector()`.

Also,

```
[CountryTraderDataParser selector];
```

is not valid unless there’s a method called `selector`. If you want to an object to execute a method based on a variable selector, use `-[NSObject performSelector:]`.

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"parse%@Address", @"DE"]);

if ([CountryTraderDataParser respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    NSLog(@"responds to");
    [CountryTraderDataParser performSelector:selector];
}
```